# How to combine array element that starts with same text in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array called `ItemArray` which has elements as below

```
ItemArray[0]='44@Man'
ItemArray[1]='45@Cotton'
ItemArray[2]='44@Woman'
```

and what I want that new array should be `NewItemArray` as below

```
NewItemArray[0]='44@Man#Woman'
NewItemArray[1]='45@Cotton'
```

Comment: Show what you've tried, we're not a free code-writing service.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints:

- you need to create an intermediate "map" from number to associated string(s)
- JS "Objects" are quite good maps
- use `.split` to break apart your original strings at the `@` sign
- the number before the `@` can be the "key" of the map
- use an *`Array`* of strings as the value in the map

If you do all that, you should end up with an object containing:

```
var tmpObj = {
     44: ['Man', 'Woman'],
     45: ['Cotton']
 };
```

- you'll need to iterate over that to create your new array
- use `.join` to combine an array of strings with a separator between each element

Comment: @Archer this is how you might write an answer that _informs_ and _educates_ without also just "giving away teh code".

Answer (score 1):

```
var ItemArray = [];
ItemArray[0]='44@Man'
ItemArray[1]='45@Cotton'
ItemArray[2]='44@Woman'

// create intermediate array of objects
var aux = {};

$.each(ItemArray, function(idx, val){
    var key = val.split("@");
    // e.g key : ['44', 'Man']
    if (!aux[key[0]]){
        aux[key[0]] = [];
    }
    aux[key[0]].push(key[1]); 
});

console.log(aux);
/* aux looks like this:
   {
     44 : ['Man', 'Woman'],
     45 : ['Cotton']
   }
*/

// create final array based on the previous temporary array
var NewItemArray = [];

$.each(aux, function(idx, val){   
    NewItemArray.push(idx + '@' + val.join("#"));
});

console.log(NewItemArray)
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T9GNm/